# jqzoom restrict small image size

Tags: jquery, image, jqzoom

I am using jqzoom which works great, however when I apply a size to the img tag on the main image, when then clicking on additional image thumbnails the images are stretched to the dimensions of the initial image.

Is there a way I can restrict the small image size (smaller than the actual image size) without other images when selected assuming the same dimensions but still being restricted and maintianing their aspect ratio?